# Docker Compose dependent named container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to bring up my container using docker compose. This container is dependent on two other containers with names 'rabbitmq' & 'mysqldb'.

What my scenario is that the dependent named containers are already created with said name. This is because of some additional configuration i needed for mysql.

How can I link those two containers to this container using docker-compose. Such that it also starts up my named containers when bringing up this myservice container.

Would appreciate any help or direction.

```
myservice:
image:  myaccount/myservice
ports:
  - "8081:8081"
restart:  always
depends_on: 
  - rabbitmq
  - mysqldb
environment:
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: 'jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/myservice'
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: 'mysql'
  SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: 'rabbitmq'
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://192.168.99.100:8081/actuator/health"]
  interval: 1m30s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3
```

**UPDATE**:

I was able to resolve this using external_links and the default bridge.

```
    version: '3'

myservice:
image:  myaccount/myservice
ports:
  - "8081:8081"
restart:  always
external_links: 
  - rabbitmq
  - mysqldb
network_mode: bridge
environment:
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: 'jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/myservice'
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: 'mysql'
  SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: 'rabbitmq'
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://192.168.99.100:8081/actuator/health"]
  interval: 1m30s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3
```

Any other alternative is appreciated. Problem is using this approach, the dependent docker containers already need to be running. However, in case the docker containers are down, I want compose to bring the same containers up. Any ideas?

Comment: depends_on should do the trick and you say that those to containers do not get created prior to myservice container?

Comment: depends_on tries creating new containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker-compose up` doesn't run already created containers. It creates the containers from an image and the runs them. So I'll make the presumption that you have images (or dockerfiles) already for these containers. However you can use `--no-recreate` with `docker-compose up` to re-use already built containers, this could be a workaround if you have a problem with the regular usage.

Under `services` in your docker-compose.yml you simply need to define a service for your other two images too. Example below.

```
services:
    service1:
        image: images/service1image
    depends_on:
     - service2
     - service3
    service2:
        image: images/service2image
    service3:
        build: docker/service3
```

You don't need to define a network as terrywb suggested if you define them this way. docker-compose automatically creates a bridge network for general use and maps ports for all defined services between them. However if you don't define them as a service then you'd likely need to define a network to connect them, of course if you do this then you won't be able to automatically start them up at the same time using docker-compose which is the whole issue you're trying to solve. If you really don't want them as services then I can only suggest you create a "startup.sh" bash/shell file to handle this. As then you'd be trying to do something outside of the functionality scope docker-compose provides.

Comment: Hi, it tried the command like below


    docker-compose up --no-recreate.  

However, its still trying to create the containers.

Comment: Please go to the documentation and read how --no-recreate works for whichever version you're using. Best to just make sure that docker and docker-compose are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to define a network in each of your docker-compose files.

```
networks:
  mynet:
```

Next, add that network to each container definition

```
myservice:
  networks:
    - mynet
```